# Schema on mongodb for reducing API calls with two collections

Tags: mongodb, subquery

Not quite sure what the best practice is if I have two collections, a user collection and a picture collection - I do not want to embed all my pictures into my user collection.

1. My client searches for pictures under a certain criteria. Let's say he gets 50 pictures back from the search (i.e. one single mongodb query). Each picture is associated to one user. I want the user name displayed as well. I assume there is no way to do a single search performance wise on the user collection returning the names of each user for each picture, i.e. I would have to do 50 searches. Which means, I could only avoid this extra performance load by duplicating data (next to the user_id, also the user_name) in my pictures collection?
2. Same question the other way around. If my client searches for users and say 50 users are returned from the search through one single query. If I want the last associated picture + title also displayed next to the user data, I would again have to add that to the users collection, otherwise I assume I need to do 50 queries to return the picture data?

Comment: That is correct, you basically have two options without modifying the structure of your collections.  1.  Store a reference to users within your pictures collection which returns the user associates with the picture, or duplicate the data.  The documentation for this is located here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say the schema for your picture collection is as such:

**Picture Document**

```
{
    _id: Objectid(123),
    url: 'img1.jpg',
    title: 'img_one',
    userId: Objectid(342)
}
```

**1)** Your picture query will return documents that look like the above. You don't have to make 50 calls to get the user associated with the images. You can simply make **1** other query to the `Users Collection` using the user ids taken from the picture documents like such:

```
db.users.find({_id: {$in[userid_1,user_id2,userid_3,...,userid_n]}})
```

You will receive an array of user documents with the user information. You'll have to handle their display on the client afterwards. At most you'll need **2** calls.

**Alternatively**

You could design the schema as such:

**Picture Document**

```
{
    _id: Objectid(123),
    url: 'img1.jpg',
    title: 'img_one',
    userId: Objectid(342),
    user_name:"user associated"
}
```

If you design it this way. You would only require **1** call, **but the username won't be in sync with user collection documents.** For example lets say a user changes their name. A picture that was saved before may have the old user name.

**2)** You could design your User Collection as such:

**User Document**

```
{
    _id: Objectid(342),
    name: "Steve jobs",
    last_assoc_img: {
           img_id: Object(342)
           url: 'img_one',
           title: 'last image title
    }
}
```

You could use the same principles as mentioned above.

Comment: thanks, that is what I was getting at. Do you know if these kind of calls: db.users.find({_id: {$in[userid_1,user_id2,userid_3,...,userid_n]}}) scale? That is, while technically not doing 50 calls, would it in terms of database load be similar to 50 queries?

Comment: just realized I only said "thanks", I meant "really, many thanks for taking the time for the detailed answer, much appreciated"

Comment: Your'e Welcome. I'm glad I can help. Yes that query scales. It won't be similar to doing 50 queries. You should use indexing on the userId if you will be querying against it often. You can see query optimization [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/):

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a `user` `id` associated with every `user` and you're also storing that `id` in the `picture` document, then your `user` <=> `picture` is a loosely coupled relationship.

In order to not have to make 50 separate calls, you can use the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) given that you are able to pull out those `id`s and put them into a list to run the second query. Your query will basically be in English: "Look at the collection, if it's in the list of `id`s, give it back to me."

If you intend on doing this a lot and intend for it to scale, I'd either recommend using a relational database or a NoSQL database that can handle joins to not force you into an embedded document schema.